# web api 2 - Oauth2 Bearer token access is forbidden

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

I have an mvc 5 application with an web api 2. (.NET 4.6)
I implemented the oauth2 configuration next to the authentication for my mvc app (app.UseCookieAuthentication) :

```
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new 
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth/token"),
        Provider = new AspNetIdentityOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider(),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1000), 
    };

    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthServerOptions);
```

My apis are protected with the Authorize Attribute (global filter).

I use the client credentials grant

I followed these two articles (that are the same)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api
https://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2017/05/10/adding-webapi-oauth-authentication-to-an-existing-project

I'm able to get a token for my user, but when I want to use the token to access my Api, I get a 403 forbidden error

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        parameters.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        parameters.Add("client_id", "4rclFahG7gho8erzbsmTbw==");
        parameters.Add("client_secret", "IBSqiYb0kT/lzV0gpQsPxkUDI9ztu0dhHWDe4VQDzKGYm2pl+75sMVfEsoGo4FAxFm0qZUFcDrVMrfqYhn2bzw==");

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:49594/oauth/token", content).Result;
            string jsonResult = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            var resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResult>(jsonResult);
            var accessToken = resultObject.access_token;


            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            result = client.GetAsync("http://localhost:49594/api/v1/echo?id=myt

estvalue").Result;

// RESULT  is 403 - Forbidden
```

I tested with postman as well, and the result is the same.

did anyone experienced the same problem ?

do you know what I' missing ?

Update :
It's working if I deploy my application on a server (azure app services) but still not on my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason of my issue !

I'm using stuntman (https://rimdev.io/stuntman/) for my dev and I forgot to configure it for oauth ...

This line was missing :

> StuntmanOptions.AllowBearerTokenPassthrough = true;